# testFailureIgnore for 1 specific test

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin

I am looking for something similar to testFailureIgnore in the maven-surefire-plugin that will only apply if one specific test fails.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Basically it is ignoring all test failures, I want it to ignore one specific failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/post/maven-surefire-debugging-execution

Their example below:

```
<plugin>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <executions>
   <execution>
     <id>applicationcomposer</id>
     <goals>
       <goal>test</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
       <groups>com.github.rmannibucau.surefire.executions.Group1</groups>
       <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
       <systemPropertyVariables>
         <openejb.jul.forceReload>true</openejb.jul.forceReload>
       </systemPropertyVariables>
     </configuration>
   </execution>
   <execution>
     <id>arquillian</id>
     <goals>
       <goal>test</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
       <excludedGroups>com.github.rmannibucau.surefire.executions.Group1</excludedGroups>
       <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
       <systemPropertyVariables>
         <java.io.tmpdir>${project.build.directory}</java.io.tmpdir>
       </systemPropertyVariables>
     </configuration>
   </execution>
 </executions>
 <configuration>
   <skip>true</skip>
   <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
   <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
   <forkCount>1</forkCount>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```